# How to use mix script of elixir on Windows?

Tags: powershell, elixir

My elixir version is Elixir 1.5.2 with OTP 20 on Windows 10. Everytime to run mix on PowerShell, I must first run command

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

Or it will tell me Program Files\Elixir\bin\mix.ps1 cannot load because there is no digital sign.

Is there any better way instead of change ExecutionPolicy every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how mix.ps1 got on your machine but either rename it or delete it. You want to run mix.bat

Comment: Thanks! I do not remove mix.ps1 since I don't know why it is there, but use mix.bat as a name works fine. Or I find I can use cmd to run mix command without rejecting.